# 'Slide' object has no attribute 'topicdetail_set'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a model for Slide on django. below is **model.py**

```
class Slide(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    topic_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("created at", auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SlideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topicdetail_set = ArticleDetailSerial(many=True)
    user_detail = FindOwnerSerializer(source='user', read_only=True)
    author = AuthorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Slide
        fields = ('id','text', 'created_at', 'topicdetail_set', 'user_detail','author')
```

When I run the url for slide http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/slide/

then I got below error

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `topicdetail_set` on serializer `SlideSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Slide` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'topicdetail_set'.
```

Now I am confused, Is the code that I have created is wrong? And if it is wrong then how should I fix it?

Comment: please show us `ArticleDetailSerial`

Comment: @xxnora thanks for your time. Actually I solved this by adding `poster = models.ForeignKey(ArticleDetail, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)` in Slide model and  modified SlideSerializer by adding `poster = models.ForeignKey(ArticleDetail, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)`. Mistake was there because of my bad coding skill.